# How to use own openssl header in libcurl on macOS

Tags: libcurl

I download and compile openssl 3.0.2 from source and want to link it with libcurl on **macOS**, however, I encounter some issues, I use latest libcurl 7.82.0.
below is configure.

> ./configure --prefix="$(pwd)/curl" --with-ssl=/Users/test/Downloads/openssl-openssl-3.0.2/openssl --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-ftp --disable-file --disable-ldap --disable-dict --disable-telnet --disable-tftp --disable-rtsp --disable-pop3 --disable-imap --disable-smtp --disable-gopher --disable-ares --disable-debug --with-zlib=/Users/test/Downloads/zlib-1.2.11/zlib --without-libidn --without-brotli --without-zstd --without-nghttp2 --without-librtmp --without-libidn2 --without-winidn

and configure result looks ok, The openssl include folder is set.

```
   Host setup:       x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
  Install prefix:   /Users/test/Downloads/curl-7.82.0/curl
  Compiler:         gcc
   CFLAGS:          -Qunused-arguments -Wno-pointer-bool-conversion -Os -Werror=partial-availability -pthread
   CPPFLAGS:        -isystem /Users/test/Downloads/zlib-1.2.11/zlib/include -isystem /Users/test/Downloads/openssl-openssl-3.0.2/openssl/include -DOPENSSL_SUPPRESS_DEPRECATED
   LDFLAGS:         -framework CoreFoundation -framework SystemConfiguration -L/Users/test/Downloads/zlib-1.2.11/zlib/lib -L/Users/test/Downloads/openssl-openssl-3.0.2/openssl/lib
   LIBS:            -lssl -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lz

  curl version:     7.82.0
  SSL:              enabled (OpenSSL v3+)
```

But when make, it will output error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_EVP_PKEY_id", referenced from:
      _ossl_connect_common in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-openssl.o)
  "_SSL_get_peer_certificate", referenced from:
      _ossl_connect_common in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-openssl.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

**Test**:
I found os installed openssl at /usr/local/include/openssl which is **1.1.1m**, After I remove this folder, The error is fixed. So I think the system installed openssl header is affected in libcurl make.

I think I have configured libcurl to use **/Users/test/Downloads/openssl-openssl-3.0.2/openssl/include**, but it does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with openSSL@3. I change to use openssl@1.1/1.1.1s and libcurl and it's working.